# How to avoid importing blanks from CSV to R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have tried using the below codes to import multiple CSV files from a folder into one data frame in R. Unfortunately, all the blanks were imported into my data frame. The number of rows should be 354 but when I imported all the CSV into my R, there are 13806 rows imported. All the rows after the 354th appeared to be NA. How do I fix this?

```
setwd("C:/Users/Documents/Folder1")
library(plyr)
alldataset <- ldply(list.files(), read.csv, header= TRUE)
```

Comment: We don't see your files, so it's hard to tell something. Consider also the possibility of filtering your data.frames  after reading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_csv` from the `readr` package has the `skip_empty_rows` option.

I generally recommend using `read_csv` rather than `read.csv`, as the former is much faster.

Comment: skip_empty_rows = TRUE by default for read_csv and read_delim.

Comment: Yes, but not in `read.csv`. There it does not exist.

Comment: True. Well, there is an option `blank.lines.skip` option in `read.csv` but this one is also true by default. In any case I would agree to use the `readr` package.

Comment: Options in `read.csv` and `read_csv` often produce different results, even when they are supposedly identical.